# How to reverse Excel's changing numbers with point delimiter automatically to date format?

Tags: excel, date, ms-office

I received an excel file where a numerical column sometimes is changed to date format like this

```
HEADER
12.3232
12.Apr
23.232
...
```

Certainly, is originally contained "12.4" instead of "12.Apr". How can I reverse this for the whole column?

Comment: If you are on the beta channel of office 365 you could use a recursive LAMBDA function - like shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7s6Dni1dG8. Instead of the replace-table used there you would have a table Jan 1, Feb 2 etc. If not then the question is, would be a VBA solution ok or are you looking for a formula

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not on the beta channel and in addition, that would be a long table for each and every possible date... I hoped there would be a faster solution, as this problem feels very common.

Comment: the replacement table would have 12 rows - one for each month ... Is `12.Apr` a true date or is it text?

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks.